# UITableview Cell Height is not calculated properly and cells overlap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I need to create and populate custom cells. These cells height are huge about 300-400.

So I have a `populateCellView` function , I call that function on `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to calculate height and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to add that view to cell content view, but somehow sometimes cells overlap.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self populateCellView:indexPath.row].frame.size.height;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UIView *populateCell= nil;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        populateCell=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [[populateCell layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];


        populateCell= [self populateCellView:indexPath.row];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:populateCell];

    }

    if (!populateCell){
        populateCell = (UIView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        populateCell= [self populateCellView:indexPath.row];

    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;

}
```

populate view function:

```
-(UIView *)populateCellView:(int)forCase
{

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width,500)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:40/255.0 green:150/255.0 blue:213/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    if ([view subviews]){
        for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }


    UILabel *caseNumberLabel;
    UILabel *caseNameLabel;
    UILabel *caseSummaryLabel;
    UILabel *caseAncLabel;


    UILabel *caseNumberText;
    UILabel *caseNameText;
    UILabel *caseSummaryText;
    UILabel *caseAncText;



    //static label for case number
    caseNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,10,250, 50)];
    caseNumberLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    caseNumberLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:24.0f];
    caseNumberLabel.text =@"Case Number:";
    caseNumberLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    caseNumberLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    caseNumberLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    caseNumberLabel.tag=forCase;
    caseNumberLabel.frame=[self calculateLabelFrame:caseNumberLabel];

    //case number from plist
    caseNumberText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(caseNumberLabel.frame.size.width+50,caseNumberLabel.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width-caseNumberLabel.frame.size.width-50, 50)];
    caseNumberText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    caseNumberText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:24.0f];
    caseNumberText.text =[[self agenda] getCaseNumber:forCase];
    caseNumberText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    caseNumberText.numberOfLines=0;
    caseNumberText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    caseNumberText.tag=forCase;
    //[caseNumberLabel sizeToFit];
    caseNumberText.frame=[self calculateLabelFrame:caseNumberText];




    //static label for case name
    caseNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,caseNumberText.frame.origin.y + caseNumberText.bounds.size.height+5,250, 50)];
    caseNameLabel.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
    caseNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:24.0f];
    caseNameLabel.text =@"Case Name:";
    caseNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    caseNameLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    caseNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    caseNameLabel.tag=forCase;
    //[caseNumberLabel sizeToFit];
    caseNameLabel.frame=[self calculateLabelFrame:caseNameLabel];

    //case name from plist
    caseNameText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(caseNameLabel.frame.size.width+50,caseNameLabel.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width-caseNameLabel.frame.size.width-50, 50)];
    caseNameText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    caseNameText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:24.0f];
    caseNameText.text =[[self agenda] getCaseName:forCase];
    caseNameText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    caseNameText.numberOfLines=0;
    //caseNameText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    caseNameText.tag=forCase;
    [caseNameText sizeToFit];
    //caseNameText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    caseNameText.frame=[self calCellLabelFrame:caseNameText previousLabel:caseNameLabel];




    //static label for case summary
    caseSummaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,caseNameText.frame.origin.y + caseNameText.bounds.size.height+20,250, 50)];
    caseSummaryLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    caseSummaryLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:24.0f];
    caseSummaryLabel.text =@"Case Summary:";
    caseSummaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    caseSummaryLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    caseSummaryLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    caseSummaryLabel.tag=forCase;

    //[caseSummaryLabel sizeToFit];
    caseSummaryLabel.frame=[self calculateLabelFrame:caseSummaryLabel];

    //case name from plist
    caseSummaryText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(caseSummaryLabel.frame.size.width+50,caseSummaryLabel.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width-caseSummaryLabel.frame.size.width-100, 50)];
    caseSummaryText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    caseSummaryText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:24.0f];
    caseSummaryText.text =[[self agenda] getCaseSummary:forCase];
    caseSummaryText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    caseSummaryText.numberOfLines=0;
    //caseSummaryText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    caseSummaryText.tag=forCase;
    [caseSummaryText sizeToFit];
    //caseSummaryText.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    caseSummaryText.frame=[self calCellLabelFrame:caseSummaryText previousLabel:caseSummaryLabel];



    //static label for anc
    caseAncLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,caseSummaryText.frame.origin.y + caseSummaryText.bounds.size.height+15,250, 50)];
    caseAncLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    caseAncLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:24.0f];
    caseAncLabel.text =@"ANC:";
    caseAncLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    caseAncLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    caseAncLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    caseAncLabel.tag=forCase;
    //[ccaseAncLabel sizeToFit];
    caseAncLabel.frame=[self calculateLabelFrame:caseAncLabel];

    //case name from plist
    caseAncText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(caseAncLabel.frame.size.width+50,caseAncLabel.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width-caseAncLabel.frame.size.width-50, 50)];
    caseAncText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    caseAncText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:24.0f];
    caseAncText.text =[[self agenda] getCaseAnc:forCase];
    caseAncText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    caseAncText.numberOfLines=0;
    //caseAncText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    caseAncText.tag=forCase;
    [caseAncText sizeToFit];
    //caseSummaryText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    caseAncText.frame=[self calCellLabelFrame:caseAncText previousLabel:caseAncLabel];


    //add button
    UIButton *acceptButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [acceptButton setTag:forCase];
    acceptButton.titleLabel.tag=1;
    [acceptButton setFrame:CGRectMake(caseAncLabel.frame.size.width+50,caseAncText.frame.origin.y +  caseAncText.bounds.size.height+20,181,39)];
    NSString *radioButtonImage=@"view_attachment.png";
    UIImage *acceptbuttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:radioButtonImage];
    [acceptButton setBackgroundImage:acceptbuttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [acceptButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showAttachements:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    //whie line
    UIView *anotherline = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,  acceptButton.frame.origin.y +  acceptButton.bounds.size.height+15, self.view.frame.size.width, 1)];
    anotherline.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    anotherline.tag=forCase;


    [view addSubview:acceptButton];

    [view addSubview: caseNumberLabel];
    [view addSubview:caseNumberText];

    [view addSubview:caseNameLabel];
    [view addSubview:caseNameText];

    [view addSubview:caseSummaryLabel];
    [view addSubview:caseSummaryText];

    [view addSubview:caseAncText];
    [view addSubview:caseAncLabel];


    [view addSubview:anotherline];
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width,anotherline.frame.origin.y + anotherline.bounds.size.height+5);

    CGFloat redLevel    = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat greenLevel  = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat blueLevel   = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;

   view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: redLevel
                                             green: greenLevel
                                              blue: blueLevel
                                             alpha: 1.0];



    return  view;


}
```

I call reload data like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_agenda loadFromPlist];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
 });
```

Any idea why cells overlaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its your UITableview cellforIndexPath causing overlap

try this

```
if (!populateCell){
    populateCell = (UIView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    populateCell= [self populateCellView:indexPath.row];

    if ([[cell contentView] subviews]){
        for (UIView *subview in [[cell contentView] subviews]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
     [[cell contentView] addSubview:populateCell];


}
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the UITableViewDataSource method, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you have to call `[[cell contentView] addSubView:populateCell]`. If the table dequeued a cell successfully, you have to retrieve the appropriate populateCell and add it to the contentView.

Answer (score 0):

If you use storyboards, and set a different height for the cells, and the rows in the tableview, the height will usually overlap. The other answers are also highly valid, but usually when I've encountered this problem, the bug lies in a different value on row height and cell height in the tableview object in your storyboard...